# Getting Last Object From Array in PFQuery (Parse)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm querying a class and key from parse. The end result should get the **last** object in the key `text` from the `array` `userPostsObjects`

Problem is `NSLog(@"FINAL OUTPUT %@", msgObject[@"text"]);` returns the whole array in the key `text` (hundreds of objects) not the last object

```
PFQuery *queryChatClass = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];

[queryChatClass selectKeys:@[@"text",
                             @"user"]];

[queryChatClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *userPostsObjects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        // Do something with the data
        for (PFObject *msgObject in userPostsObjects) {

            NSLog(@"FINAL OUTPUT %@", msgObject[@"text"]);

        }
    }
    else {

        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

My best guess was to use `for (PFObject *msgObject in [userPostsObjects lastObject])`

However this results in:  `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14567300'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `lastObject`, you can just "do something with the data" without iterating (you have just one object, not an array); i.e.:

```
NSLog(@"FINAL OUTPUT %@", [userPostsObjects lastObject][@"text"]);
```